# Django not displaying form labels

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

My forms.py is this:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    query = forms.CharField(
    label='Enter a keyword to search for',
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': 32})
    )
```

and my views.py is this:

```
if request.GET.has_key('query'):
    query = request.GET['query'].strip() #remove white spaces
    if query: #if the query still exists with no white spaces
        form = SearchForm({'query' : query})
        search_results = Bookmark.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)

    variables = {
        'form':form,
        'search_results':search_results,
    }

return render(request, 'home_page.html', variables)
```

As you can see, i'm not doing the usual

```
form = SearchForm(request.GET)
```

I'm doing

```
form = SearchForm({'query' : query})
```

and this is my template:

```
<form id="search-form" method="get" action=".">
    <p>{{ form.query }}</p>
    <input type="submit" value="search" />
</form>
```

and it is not showing the label. when I replace

```
<p>{{ form.query }}</p>
```

with

```
<p>{{ form.as_p }}</p>
```

it displays label correctly. Any idea why it doesn't work when it is

```
<p>{{ form.query }}</p>
```

? Could it be because I am doing

```
form = SearchForm({'query' : query})
```

in my view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to display the label when you are just displaying a single field. `{{ form.query }}` just displays the input. Use `{{ form.query.label_tag }}` for the label. Like this:

```
<p>{{ form.query.label_tag }} {{ form.query }}</p>
```